# Azure CLI isn't installed on a ASP.NET Core WebApp

Tags: azure-cli

I used Kudu to open a CMD on my ASP.NET Core WebApp but Azure CLI doesn't seem to be installed as when I enter az --version an error appears "az is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

I have a WebJob written in C# that can run a PowerShell script, but as the Azure CLI doesn't seem to be installed on ASP.NET Core WebApp images I am wondering what other options there are for programmatically starting and deleting Azure Containers?

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is not really supported for Kudu.

If you need to make Azure calls in you ASP.NET web app, then you can use the [Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-sdk-azure-get-started) in your web app.